# ClassNotFoundError in Symfomy 6 project

Tags: symfony, symfonyux

I have this error on my Symfony 6.0 project:

Attempted to load class "TwigComponentBundle" from namespace "Symfony\UX\TwigComponent".

Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?

When I'm doing a "composer require symfony/framework-bundle -W", here's my Terminal output:

```
./composer.json has been updated
Running composer update symfony/twig-bundle
Loading composer repositories with package information
Info from https://repo.packagist.org: #StandWithUkraine
Updating dependencies
Nothing to modify in lock file
Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev)
Nothing to install, update or remove
Package league/uri-parser is abandoned, you should avoid using it. No replacement was suggested.
Package deployer/phar-update is abandoned, you should avoid using it. No replacement was suggested.
Generating optimized autoload files
106 packages you are using are looking for funding.
Use the `composer fund` command to find out more!

Run composer recipes at any time to see the status of your Symfony recipes.

Executing script cache:clear [KO]
 [KO]
Script cache:clear returned with error code 255
!!  Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Error\ClassNotFoundError {#92
!!    #message: """
!!      Attempted to load class "TwigComponentBundle" from namespace "Symfony\UX\TwigComponent".\n
!!      Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?
!!      """
!!    #code: 0
!!    #file: "D:\pierre\projets\catalogue services\docker\php8\catalogue\vendor\symfony\framework-bundle\Kernel\MicroKernelTrait.php"
!!    #line: 132
!!    trace: {
!!      D:\pierre\projets\catalogue services\docker\php8\catalogue\vendor\symfony\framework-bundle\Kernel\MicroKernelTrait.php:132 { …}
!!      D:\pierre\projets\catalogue services\docker\php8\catalogue\vendor\symfony\http-kernel\Kernel.php:386 { …}
!!      D:\pierre\projets\catalogue services\docker\php8\catalogue\vendor\symfony\http-kernel\Kernel.php:128 { …}
!!      D:\pierre\projets\catalogue services\docker\php8\catalogue\vendor\symfony\framework-bundle\Console\Application.php:168 { …}
!!      D:\pierre\projets\catalogue services\docker\php8\catalogue\vendor\symfony\framework-bundle\Console\Application.php:74 { …}
!!      D:\pierre\projets\catalogue services\docker\php8\catalogue\vendor\symfony\console\Application.php:171 { …}
!!      D:\pierre\projets\catalogue services\docker\php8\catalogue\vendor\symfony\runtime\Runner\Symfony\ConsoleApplicationRunner.php:54 { …}
!!      D:\pierre\projets\catalogue services\docker\php8\catalogue\vendor\autoload_runtime.php:35 { …}
!!      D:\pierre\projets\catalogue services\docker\php8\catalogue\bin\console:11 {
!!        ›
!!        › require_once dirname(__DIR__).'/vendor/autoload_runtime.php';
!!        ›
!!        arguments: {
!!          "D:\pierre\projets\catalogue services\docker\php8\catalogue\vendor\autoload_runtime.php"
!!        }
!!      }
!!    }
!!  }
!!  2023-06-14T08:57:53+00:00 [critical] Uncaught Error: Class "Symfony\UX\TwigComponent\TwigComponentBundle" not foundtype here
```

Here's my composer.json:

```
{
    "name": "symfony/website-skeleton",
    "type": "project",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "description": "A skeleton to start a new Symfony website",
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.2.5",
        "ext-ctype": "*",
        "ext-iconv": "*",
        "amphp/http-client": "^4.6",
        "composer/package-versions-deprecated": "1.11.99.4",
        "doctrine/annotations": "^1.0",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^2.4",
        "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "^3.1",
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.10",
        "phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock": "^5.2",
        "symfony/asset": "^5.3",
        "symfony/config": "^5.4",
        "symfony/console": "^5.3",
        "symfony/dependency-injection": "^5.4",
        "symfony/dotenv": "^5.3",
        "symfony/expression-language": "^5.3",
        "symfony/finder": "^5.4",
        "symfony/flex": "^1.16",
        "symfony/form": "^5.3",
        "symfony/framework-bundle": "^5.3",
        "symfony/http-client": "^5.3",
        "symfony/intl": "^5.3",
        "symfony/mailer": "^5.3",
        "symfony/mime": "^5.3",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.1",
        "symfony/notifier": "^5.3",
        "symfony/process": "^5.3",
        "symfony/property-access": "^5.3",
        "symfony/property-info": "^5.3",
        "symfony/proxy-manager-bridge": "^5.3",
        "symfony/requirements-checker": "^2.0",
        "symfony/runtime": "^5.3",
        "symfony/security-bundle": "^5.3",
        "symfony/serializer": "^5.3",
        "symfony/stimulus-bundle": "^2.9",
        "symfony/string": "^5.3",
        "symfony/translation": "^5.3",
        "symfony/twig-bundle": "^5.3",
        "symfony/validator": "^5.3",
        "symfony/web-link": "^5.3",
        "symfony/web-profiler-bundle": "^5.3",
        "symfony/webpack-encore-bundle": "^1.14",
        "symfony/yaml": "^5.3",
        "twig/extra-bundle": "^2.12|^3.0",
        "twig/twig": "^2.12|^3.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "andres-montanez/magallanes": "^4.0",
        "deployer/deployer": "^6.8",
        "symfony/browser-kit": "^5.3",
        "symfony/css-selector": "^5.3",
        "symfony/debug-bundle": "^5.3",
        "symfony/maker-bundle": "^1.0",
        "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "^5.3",
        "symfony/stopwatch": "^5.3"
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": {
            "*": "dist"
        },
        "sort-packages": true,
        "allow-plugins": {
            "symfony/flex": true,
            "symfony/runtime": true
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "replace": {
        "symfony/polyfill-ctype": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-iconv": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php72": "*"
    },
    "conflict": {
        "symfony/symfony": "*"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "auto-scripts": {
            "cache:clear": "symfony-cmd",
            "assets:install %PUBLIC_DIR%": "symfony-cmd",
            "requirements-checker": "script"
        },
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ]
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony": {
            "allow-contrib": false,
            "require": "^5.3",
            "docker": true
        }
    }
}
```

Bundles.php here:

```
<?php

return [
    Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle::class => ['dev' => true, 'test' => true],
    Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Symfony\Bundle\DebugBundle\DebugBundle::class => ['dev' => true],
    Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Doctrine\Bundle\MigrationsBundle\DoctrineMigrationsBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Twig\Extra\TwigExtraBundle\TwigExtraBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Symfony\Bundle\MakerBundle\MakerBundle::class => ['dev' => true],
    Symfony\UX\TwigComponent\TwigComponentBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Symfony\UX\LiveComponent\LiveComponentBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Symfony\WebpackEncoreBundle\WebpackEncoreBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Symfony\UX\Vue\VueBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Symfony\UX\Autocomplete\AutocompleteBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Symfony\UX\StimulusBundle\StimulusBundle::class => ['all' => true],
];
```

Any help or anyone who also did encountered such an error ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

run `composer require symfony/ux-twig-component`

[See the docs here](https://symfony.com/bundles/ux-twig-component/current/index.html#installation)

Comment: Hi @craigh. Thanks. I already did that and it didn't fix anything and I thought it was obvious because I already did it a longtime ago. I also restart my PC :could it be a reason that fixed it? Anyway, thank you!

Comment: the composer file you posted indicates the library is not required.